# How can make disable view with Notification request?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

How can activate and disable local notification?

First time when i open app is appear this view with notification request. How make disappear this alertView for notification, at start of application? I want use a switch in settings for this.

So, it's a way to transform this code from AppDelegate, in a switch from settingsView?

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Or i can set from start to on notifications? And after i use switch for create or not the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in settingsView.m file

```
       - (IBAction)switchValueChanged:(id)sender
     {
if (self.switchNotificationSetting.isOn)
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
 }
```

second time onward it will not show alert, either user allow notification or disallow, alert appear only once.
you need to add iboutlet and action of uiswitch

Comment: Maybe after time, the user want to change to on, or off.

Comment: alert for permission comes only once. you can't show alert for permission programmatically. see apple guideline for notification permmission.

Comment: once user disallow for notification to your app, you can't send notification nor you can ask again for permssion. it's irritating for user as per apple say.